# Need help understanding mathematical formula for ellipse in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, animation, math, formula

Need help understanding this code, which is used to make an image move in an elliptical shape. What I don't understand, is the formula for e, px and py variable. What exactly is the e variable defined the complex way it is? I know it uses some mathematical formulas but i don't know which ones.

```
         var b = 125;
         var h = 115;
         var rx = 7;
         var ry = 4;  
         var e = 0; 

    function update() {
        setInterval(function() {
            e = (e + Math.PI / 360) % (Math.PI * 2);
            rotate(e);
        }, 10);

        var lyd = new Audio("Vedlegg/skoytelyd.mp3");
        lyd.play();
    }

    function rotate(e) {
        var px = b + rx * Math.cos(e)*b/2; 
        var py = h + ry * Math.sin(e)*h/2;

        document.getElementById("punkt").style.left = px + "px";
        document.getElementById("punkt").style.top = py + "px"; 
    }
    </script>
    <style>
        div {
            position: fixed;
        }
        #sentrum {
            background: black;
            left: 100px;
            top: 50px;
        }

        #skoyteloper {
            position: absolute;
            top: 190px;
            left: 450px;
            width: 60px;
            height: 60px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="sentrum"></div>
        <img src="Vedlegg/bane.jpg" id="imgBane"></img>
    </div>
    <div id="punkt">
        <img src="Vedlegg/skoyteloper.png" id="skoyteloper"></img>
    </div>
    <a href="animasjon.html">TILBAKE</a>
</body>
```

Comment: `e` here is the angle of the rotation, in radiants. It goes between 0 and `pi * 2`. Geometrically, is the length of a string following the arc of the circle with radius 1. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand how the formula makes the image move elliptical? @Jacopofar

Comment: If you set rx and ry to 1 the formula produces a circle, with b & h as center.  rx gives a factor to each x-coordinate.  For example rx=2 => instead of a circle you get a squashed circle (called ellipse), where the x-coordinate is twice as far from center than each y-coordinate. (dito but reversed for ry)

Comment: Thanks, @EmmanuelDelay but are the cos and sin values of the e variable the x-coordinate and the y-coordinate?

Answer (score 0):

Sinus and cosinus: 
Think of a triangle with one 90° angle.  1 line is horizontal, another line is at the right side and is vertical, the third line goes from bottom-left to top-right.
The angle on the left we call e (yes,it is the e in your function)

sinus of e is defined as the vertical line on the right divided by the diagonal line; cosinus e = horizontal line (which is touching the angle e) / diagonal.

--

Now draw a circle with middle at angle e and radius = the length of the diagonal.
If you raise the angle e you will see the vertical line get bigger and the horizontal line get smaller (keep the length of the diagonal constant),  until you reach 90°.  Then of course you can go beyond 90°, then the vertical line can be on the left.  Further than 180° the vertical line will point down (negative coordinate), ...

So that's one of the uses of sin and cos: if you set an angle they give you an y-value and a x-value, showing you 1 point on a circle.  It's always a number between -1 and +1.  example: sin(0) = 0  (no vertical component), cos(0) = 1

This code here below gives you a circle around center (0,0) and radius 100.  Feed this function a bunch of values for e and you get as many points on a circle

```
function rotate(e) {
    var px = 100 * Math.cos(e); 
    var py = 100 * Math.sin(e);
}
```

Now, if instead of 100 * cos(e) you put 200 * cos(e), then it's not a circle anymore.  Every x coordinate will be twice as far (compared to the circle).  A different rx and ry will result in an ellipse.

your variables b & h are for pushing the center of the ellipse to somewhere inside the image/div/canvas/... rather than in a corner (then you clip most of the ellipse).

Does this help?